# contextMenuStrip click events in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, contextmenustrip

Is there an event that fires in vb.net just before a contextMenuStrip appears when the user right clicks on a control?  I need to be able to control the content of the contextMenuStrip just prior to the menu strip appearing.  Basically I want to be able to change the content of the contextMenuStrip just before it appears.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the [Opening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) event.